# DirectShow stops working when locking and unlocking windows

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

i wrote a very simple program that uses DirectShow to play some media files. However, whenever I re-size videos then lock and unlock my computer or hit ctrl + alt + del, the program (DirectShow specifically) crashes. If I don't re-size the videos, it doesn't crash. I wonder if there is any that i need to know about this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

PS: I have tested this issue with the PlayWnd-2008 project sample in the DirectShowSample package downloaded from DirectShow page. It still shows the same behavior. I got "vshost-clr2.exe has stopped working" message, and have no idea where to put a break point to learn about this error.

Comment: It's your application which crashes, not DirectShow. To troubleshoot the crash you need to attach with debugger and make it break on exception to take you to the crash point for further investigation.

Comment: I have tested this issue with the PlayWnd-2008 project sample in the DirectShowSample package downloaded from DirectShow page. It still shows the same behavior. I got "vshost-clr2.exe has stopped working" message, and have no idea where to put a break point to learn about this error.